# product of two algebras is still a algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $A$ and $B$ two $R$-algebras, is $A\times B$ still an $R$-algebra? If so, what's the relation between  $A\times B$ and $A\otimes B$?

Comment: What difficulty do you have in verifying whether $A\times B$ is an $R$-algebra?

Comment: This question came out when I was taking an algebra class, the instructor said it's not an algebra, but I thought it is after my verification. So I'm not sure if anything goes wrong.

Comment: If $f:R\to A$ and $g:R\to B$ are the maps giving the $R$-algebra structure, then the map taking $r\in R$ to $(f(r),g(r))$ seems to establish the $R$-algebra structure on $A\times B$ no?

Answer (score 2):

The product $A\times B$ is an $R$-algebra, just defining all the operations (including multiplication by elements of $R$) coordinatewise.  It doesn't have any particular relation to $A\otimes B$, though.

(If all your rings are commutative, then the two constructions are in a certain sense dual: $A\times B$ is the *product* of $A$ and $B$ and $A\otimes_R B$ is the *coproduct* of $A$ and $B$ (in the category of commutative $R$-algebras).)

Comment: Thank you! It's very clear!