# Give an non-example that a commutative finite-dimensional algebra might fail to be a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The post [Proof that an integral domain that is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space is in fact a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63950/1017322) has proved that under the restriction that the algebra admits no zero-divisors, it is a field. I wonder whether this condition is necessary. Can anyone construct a commutative finite-dimensional algebra that is not a field?

Comment: How about the $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$? Note in this example, $(1,0)$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: How is the multiplication defined?

Comment: Coordinate-wise, also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638026/product-of-two-algebras-is-still-a-algebra

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also keep in mind $\mathbb R[\epsilon]$ where $\epsilon ^2 = 0 $.